# Window in a Window

Tags: android, layout, widget, window

I am coding an app an I want to use a result screen like in Angry Birds:

http://img.uptodown.net/screen/webapps/bigthumb/angry-birds-10.jpg

Is there a widget for this window in the main-window or have I to implement a overlayed layout which is on every layout?

Comment: It's a `View` overlaying the current view. Simply change the visibility or x/y coordinates as needed to show or hide the overlay.

Comment: so there is no special widget like "little window in main screen", right ?

Comment: There is a `Dialog` Object, but you will not get the customization you are looking for without a `View`. You can customize a dialog if you *need* a new window, however I haven't seen that done too often.

Comment: I'm going to take the overlay solution it's easier

Comment: To help close to the question, I added these comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Dialog` Object that will provide a separate window, but to get the customization you are looking for, the best approach is the simply use a `View`, and change the visibility or x and y coordinates as needed to show or hide the *popup*.